How to test that recomposition hasn't happened?
I had a bug where recomposition was pointlessly happening on list items in my lazyColumn when only 1 item was modified. The issue is fixed now, but in spirit of TDD I want to create an Android test that prevents it from happening in the future. However I haven't found anything that's like:
items.onChildAt(3).assertRecompositionCount(0)
items.onChildAt(4).assertRecompositionCount(1)

Does anyone know of anything to help me achieve this?

Posting a hacky answer I found to this, using a custom boolean semantic
val TestRecomposed = SemanticsPropertyKey<Boolean>(
  name = "TestRecomposed"
)

var SemanticsPropertyReceiver.testRecomposed: Boolean
  get() = throw IllegalArgumentException("Cannot get this semantic property manually")
  set(value) = set(TestRecomposed, value)

then in my composable:
Modifier.semantics { testRecomposed = true }

and then in tests:

@Test
fun myTest() {
    lazyColumn.onChildAt(2).assertRecomposed()
    lazyColumn.onChildAt(3).assertRecomposed()
    
    // do things that cause child at index 3 to recompose

    lazyColumn.onChildAt(2).assertDidNotRecompose()
    lazyColumn.onChildAt(3).assertRecomposed()
}

fun SemanticsNodeInteraction.assertRecomposed() =
    assert(SemanticsMatcher("${TestRecomposed.name} = 'true'") {
      val recomposed = (it.config.getOrElseNullable(TestRecomposed) { null } == true)
      config[TestRecomposed] = false
      recomposed && it.config.getOrElseNullable(TestRecomposed) { null } == false
})

fun SemanticsNodeInteraction.assertDidNotRecompose() =
    assert(SemanticsMatcher("${TestRecomposed.name} = 'false'") {
      it.config.getOrElseNullable(TestRecomposed) { null } == false
})

However I'm certain there must be a more elegant, less hacky and more comprehensive way to do this, so please share if you have a good idea :).
